# What's the difference between `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` and `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN`?

Tags: github-actions, npm-registry

I'm using some github action to release one of my package in a mono repo, holding about 4-5 package likes:

```
github-repository (monorepo):
- folder_1 (package 1)
- folder_2 (package 2)
- folder_3 (package 3)
```

For each packages located in this monorepo, when a tag matching a version is released, the action will release it, using a workflow (almost identical for all packages):

```yaml
name: package 1
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - package1/v*

permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: write

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.12
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: folder_1

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@ab597985615ec2ede58e132d2621d2b1cbd6127c

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: .github/actions/secure-setup-node
        with:
          path: folder_1

      - name: install dependencies
        run: yarn --frozen-lockfile
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: build package
        run: yarn build

      - name: add package.json
        run: cp package.json ./dist

      - name: add yarn.lock
        run: cp yarn.lock ./dist

      - name: add README.md
        run: cp README.md ./dist

      - run: yarn publish ./dist
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

each packages have their own action's workflow `.yaml` and works fine, except for the new package I just created: `package 4 (located in github-repository/folder_4)`.

it's a basic package except it only holds config files, so it's `yarn build` script will only copy theses file in the `./dist` folder, without implying node or javascript, making it's workflow looking like:

```
name: Config Release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - package4/v*

permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: write

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: folder_4

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@a55da8c3cf115ac326823e79a1e1788f7940201b

      - name: build package
        run: yarn build

      - run: yarn publish ./dist
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But here goes the issue ! running this action will result by:

```
Run yarn publish ./dist
yarn publish v1.22.19
[1/4] Bumping version...
info Current version: 1.0.0
[2/4] Logging in...
error No token found and can't prompt for login when running with --non-interactive.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/publish for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I checked a lot of documentation or github issues about this matter and managed to fix my problem, by replacing `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` by `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN`, but why did it solved it when all my previous packages are still using `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` ? is it because I'm not using `setup-node` ? (I don't use it because I'm not using node to build my javascript), because I don't have `yarn.lock` ? (even an empty one),

What's the difference about these 2 ? in [this issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/81) someone told that:

> NPM_AUTH_TOKEN work for npm registry

> NODE_AUTH_TOKEN work for scope registry

what does it mean ?

Comment: Do you have `.npmrc` and/or `.yarnrc`? What do your `package.json` files look like? These articles [https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages) and [Working with the npm registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry) explain all these things in detail. Also, see these official docs for [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scope).

Comment: @Azeem I'm pleased to have an answer, but my `package.json` is barely empty (no dependencies / devDependencies, only repository, author, name, version, license and "build" scripts), and I don't have any `.npmrc` / `.yarnrc`.
It's not a deploy issues, I already deployed over 200 release on other packages with the exact same config file, it's just for this project, and I managed to solve the problem, it's just I don't understand the difference between `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` and `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN`

Comment: Thank you! Right. I spent quite some time yesterday to find something concrete on it but unfortunately could not. Regarding scoped package, it depends on the `name` field of your package. You can verify it on your side. Apart from that, I suspected that you might have configured the token variable in the `.npmrc` or `.yarnrc` like that i.e. `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` and that's why it didn't work with `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN`; but, you don't have these files. `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` seems to be working with `npm` but you're using `yarn`.

Comment: I stumbled upon a GitHub thread where the precedence of `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc` was discussed for `yarn`. But, you don't use either of those. Not sure why it's even working with `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN`. :-) If you could create a sample repo replicating your use case, I'll try to test that on my side to figure this out in detail.

Comment: I suspect it's because I don't use [secure-setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#publish-to-npmjs-and-gpr-with-npm) script for this peculiar package, and I guess it automatically add this env variable :/

Comment: Yes, `setup-node` creates a `.npmrc` and internally it uses it. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages#about-package-configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPM_AUTH_TOKEN is a token generated in NPM. You then put that in your [GitHub secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) on GitHub so it can be passed to an action. You shouldn't put the token in your workflow file. You use it with a "Publish to NPM" GitHub Action. For example in this file `.github/workflows/npm-publish.yml`:

```
jobs:
  npm-publish:
    ...
    steps:
      ...
      env:
        NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

The NODE_AUTH_TOKEN is an environment variable with your NPM_TOKEN secret. Ultimately this is used to publish Node.js packages in a continuous integration (CI) workflow.

```
jobs:
  build:
    ...
    steps:
      ...
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

The setup-node action creates your `.npmrc` file and references your NODE_AUTH_TOKEN environment variable:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

Make sure to set registry-url to https://registry.npmjs.org/ in setup-node.

There is a [walk through for setting up the CI publishing here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages).

Comment: So `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` is a token that's used to publish to NPM, whereas `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` is used to publish to NPM. Got it.

Comment: @scubbo yeah. I got it too. :D

Answer (score 2):

When Github run this action `actions/setup-node` if you define `registry-url` property then it write it in `.npmrc` file with `_authToken` that read its value from `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` env, the file will looks something like this

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
always-auth=true
```

You can read about it here [doc](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/)

And that is why the env var must be named `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` otherwise the file `.npmcr` will fail to evaluate the value of the variable

There is nothing in documentation regarding `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` but I assume if it works when rename to it, then it has been used somewhere in similar way to `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN`.