401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@company%2fpackage - authentication token not provided
Given a private Github project using the Github npm package registry ( the published npm package and this project are controlled by the same organization ).
The project uses this .npmrc file
@organization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org

always-auth=true
save-exact=true

and during CI Github Actions is running these steps
name: QA

on: pull_request

jobs:
  qa:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 22.x

      - name: Setup npm login
        run: npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      # ...

It seems the GITHUB_TOKEN is not enough ( see How to solve "Permission permission_denied: read_package" in a GitHub Actions workflow targeting the GitHub packages registry? ) so we created an ADMIN_TOKEN with full permissions.
Unfortunately the install step fails with the error message
Run npm install
npm error code E401
npm error 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@organization%2fpackage - authentication token not provided
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-09-19T13_40_26_149Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Does someone know how to fix this?

This question/answers may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75766122/14072498

Maybe adding the authentication token to your .npmrc file would solve this?
You could tweak the pre installation step - run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc Let us know if that works.

@HariReddy sorry, that didn't work. The Setup npm login step should deal with the login

You just need to use github.token like this. Note that I'm using a custom action only because there's no skip-duplicate in the npm publish command, and it would fail the workflow if the package version is already in the registry

You've left out most of your YAML file, but I assume you are using actions/setup-node?
Can you make sure you have defined your registry URL like this:
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/

Then while installing your dependencies pass your auth token as a env variable like so:
     - name: Install dependencies
       run: npm install
       env:
         NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN}}

This is how I had it configured in my project and worked for me. I am using setup-node@v3 if you are curious.
EDIT:
My .npmrc looks like this, but I am not sure if it will affect much.
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
@company:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/


Hm now the error is npm error notarget No matching version found for @company/package@1.5.0. but it does exist in the registry...

Maybe try using npm ci (for a clean install. Might be something with your node_modules). That is what I could find from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039375/stuck-while-installing-packages-npm-err-notarget-no-matching-version-found-for

As Wessel has already mentioned, you should call the actions/setup-node@v3 action at the beginning of your GH Action instead of manually setting up Node with npm commands. What I would recommend is specifying the scope of the package as well. Since you have not provided a scope in the setup-node action, the action will fall back to the repository owner. I don't know who your repo owner is, so I'm working off the assumption that the repo owner is not the same as the scope of the package. (I know you had said the same org controls the package and the repo, so this is kind of a long shot but I figured it can't hurt)
Try this action definition, and see if it works for you! I did write it with v4 instead of v3, but v3 should work the same if you're limited to that for some reason 
As a side note, specifying a registry-url with actions/setup-node@v4 will automatically set up auth to read from env.NODE_AUTH_TOKEN. If you don't have your token set in env.NODE_AUTH_TOKEN, you can set it in https://github.com/@company/your-repo/settings/secrets/actions or you can pass it in the step
steps:
- uses: actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/'
    scope: '@company'

# Run a clean install
- run: npm ci
# Pass the token to the environment variable if not configured globally
# env:
#   NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}


Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002895/401-unauthorized-get-https-npm-pkg-github-com-company2fpackage-authentic/79035017#comment139334913_79017896

A couple questions: Have you validated that the token has access to that package? And, have you validated that that version of the package actually exists? Not the package itself, but the version. If it's telling you the package doesn't exist, that means it is authenticating but not finding it, so that's a separate issue. You can list all versions of the package by using npm view @company/package versions

As a side note, be sure to run that within the Action runner so it utilizes the admin token you created and you can validate its permissions as well as verify the version of the package it's trying to install, 1.5.0, actually exists.
